# In Makefile, how to depend on the fact that the docker compose services are up?

Tags: docker-compose, makefile

In Makefile, I want to start services to run some commands.

How to ensure that those services are up only for some target?

Ex:

```
build:
    docker compose run php composer install
```

This command require the stack to be up and running...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can detect the docker compose stack status with:

```
DC_TARGETS=$(shell docker compose config --services | sort | xargs echo)
DC_RUNNING=$(shell docker compose ps --services --status="running" )
ifeq ($(DC_TARGETS), $(DC_RUNNING))
    DC_MUST_START=
else
    DC_MUST_START=start-containers
endif
```

After, for targets that require the stack to be up:

```
build: $(DC_MUST_START)
    docker compose exec php composer install
```

PS: start-containers is a makefile target... that start the containers

Comment: If it's supposed to be a makefile target it should be listed as a prerequisite, not inside the recipe.